# Redirecting one subdomain in Nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm a bit stuck on this one and any assistance would be amazing. I'm very much an Nginx noob.

We have an existing Nginx setup with lots of redirections already configured.

I'm trying to only redirect one subdomain in Nginx to an external url, however no matter what I try it redirects all subdomains.

I've reviewed our existing configs to get some understanding of how things are setup but the life of me I just can't work this one out and all the search results I seem to find are for redirecting all subdomains or sub sites not for redirecting just one subdomain of many.

This subdomain didn't have an existing config and I've had to create one (copy one of our others and edit it) it looks like previously the subdomain was configured under a catch all.

Example:

I need https://foo-bar.test.com.au to redirect to https://externalURL.com

However I don't want https://other-site.test.com.au to redirect to https://externalURL.com

This is the current config

---

server {

server_name foo-bar.test.com.au;

rewrite ^ https://externalURL.com;

root /opt/nginx-static/foo-bar;

}

server {

listen 443 ssl http2;

server_name foo-bar.test.com.au;

rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://externalURL;

ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/foo-bar.crt;

ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/foo-bar.key;

ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;

ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

ssl_session_timeout 30m;

root /opt/nginx-static/foo-bar;

location / {

root /opt/nginx-static/foo-bar;

index index.html foo-bar.html;

autoindex on;

}

}

Answer (score 1):

I got this figured out.
Turns out the order of the .conf files matters
Renamed the config to zz.foo-bar.conf so it comes after default.conf

Also the permissions weren't set correctly on /opt/nginx-static/foo-bar

The other piece of the puzzle was DNS, I'd altered it earlier in my troubleshooting, turns out I needed to revert it back to the original DNS entry.